# OpenXml Cannot open package because FileMode or FileAccess value is not valid for the stream

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

The stream comes from an html form via ajax `var jqXHR = data.submit();`

```
public static GetWordPlainText(Stream readStream,string filePath)
{
   WordprocessingDocument.Open(readStream, readStream.CanRead);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload() 
{
 var MyFile = Request.Files[0];
 if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && MyFile != null)
 {
  GetWordPlainText(Request.InputStream);
 }
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot open package because FileMode or FileAccess value is not valid
>   for the stream.

I google *Cannot open package because FileMode or FileAccess value is not valid for the stream* but can't find anything useful. Any ideas?

PS: Initially I simplified the code to be posted here to much. Added the if statement so that it would erase the concern by Sten Petrov. I hope Request.File.count>0 does address his concern... I still have the same problem...

## UPDATE

As a work around I followed the advise below and save the file to a directory then I use openxml to read it from the directory

```
  var MyFile = Request.Files[0];
  var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/temp"), MyFile.FileName);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //if file exist plz!!!! TODO

                    Request.Files[0].InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, ms.ToArray());
                }
```

then `WordprocessingDocument.Open` has a implementation for filepath so
`WordprocessingDocument.Open(path);` hope you get the idea of what I did for future people that have problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is asking for trouble, because the Request stream may not have fully been downloaded.

I suggest you download the file first into a MemoryStream or as a file, [see here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) for the latter option, then do whatever you want to the uploaded file.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the stream is not correctly opened with read or readwrite access.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc536138.aspx) about WordprocessingDocument.Open method (Stream, Boolean)

> IOException: 
>   Thrown when "stream" is not opened with Read (ReadWrite) access.

Comment: I will look into this possible solution. For know I done what Petrov recommended.

Answer (score 2):

The method `WordprocessingDocument.Open` is defined as:

```
public static WordprocessingDocument Open(Stream stream, bool isEditable)
```

You're passing the value of `readStream.CanRead` as the second parameter. This doesn't seem correct to me. When `CanRead` is `true`, indicating that the stream can be read, you're trying to open the `WordprocessingDocument` as editable, which the stream probably doesn't support. I would just pass `false` for the second parameter. Otherwise, pass `readStream.CanWrite` but don't be surprised if this property always returns `false` (as I would expect when dealing with streams from uploaded files).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc536138.aspx

Comment: WordprocessingDocument.open has several overloads one namely being stream,bool. However, i will try to set it to false and let you know if I was able to use the stream instead of the lame write to file then use the string overload of WordprocessingDocument.open

Comment: Sorry, yes. I meant to post the `(Stream, bool)` method signature and got the wrong one. Just fixed that. The point I was trying to make is that when the second parameter to this method is `true`, it requires the underlying stream to be editable, and your uploaded stream is not.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but with **ClosedXML.Excel** library. I was downloading file using simple *WebRequest* instance and I my problem was that Stream got closed with *WebRequest* disposal so I had to copy it. For the "safety" I used *MemoryStream*.

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
     response.GetResponseStream()?.CopyTo(memStream);
}

XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(memSream);
```

*CopyTo* is to ensure stream is available after *WebRequest* is disposed.